# How pymongo define the key for append the value

Tags: python, pymongo

#### Mongodb collections like this:

```
 `col={"a":{"x":1,"y":2},"b":[{"w":5,"z":7},{"w":8,"z":5}]}`
```

#### It works in pymongo:

```
 `col.find({"a.x":1}) or col.find({"b.w":5})`
```

#### now I want create a list to append the value of the key like "a.x" or "b.w",I write the code as follows,but get noting.

```
 `data1=[]
 data2=[]
 finddata={}
 for data in col.find({}):
    finddata=dict(data)
    for key,value in finddata.items():
       if key == "a.x":      #if key=="a" will works
          data1.append(value)
       if key == "b.w":
          data2.append(value)`
```

Can anyone help me?Thanks

Comment: Why is the values not retrieved from the database instead?
It's unnecessary work to be retrieving the values in the Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the best way to solve this problem,Create a Dict of data that find in database.then define the key that you want choose as 'objkey'

```
def get_dict_in(Dict,objkey,default):
  for key,value in Dict.items():
    if key == objkey:
        return value
    else:
        if type(value) is dict:  # Note: import types
            val=get_dict_in(value,objkey,default)
            if default not in val:
                return val
return default
```

e.g.

```
dictA={"a":{"x":1,"y":2},"b":[{"w":5,"z":7},{"w":8,"z":5}]}
value=get_dict_in(dictA,'x',None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Mongo aggregation pipeline, the fields you care about can be projected and made to replace the returned fields in the returned root document. *e.g.*

```
pipeline = [
    {'$project': {'a.x':1, 'b.w': 1}},
    {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': {'a_x': '$a.x', 'b_w': '$b.w'}}}
] 

cur = db.keyes.aggregate(pipeline)
result = next(cur)
```

This way, you can go ahead to extend the respective lists using the result.

```
tolist = lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]

data1.extend(tolist(result['a_x']))
data2.extend(tolist(result['b_w']))
```

Comment: The output of  "result=next(cur) should be 'a_x':1,'b_w':1  right ? But I get empty value like 'a_w':[ ],'b_w':[ ]

Comment: No, it should be `{'a_w':1, 'b_w': [5, 8]}`. I used the sample you provided for `col`

Comment: Yes,I got that, My problem is the return value is empty when I use this way to deal with a big database about thousands of records

Comment: Did you find the reason why it's empty? What did you do to resolve it?

Comment: I print 'cur' and found most of them are empty,a few not,the result of next(cur) is always the first one ,I write a while loop to extend the value to the data list.Thanks.

Comment: The results of aggregate(pipeline) are all data that have same Key,Do you know about how to limit the results like db.find() function.